# What does the question: "Any value in this?" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

This question was used in the following context: a feature was suggested for implementation in an application; this question was added as a comment. How to interpret it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means:

> Is it **worthwhile** to do this?"

See [***value***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/value):

> 5. that quality of a thing according to which it is thought of as being more or less desirable, useful, estimable, important, etc.; worth or the degree of worth